# OnClickListener not working when i click on text

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

when click on text nothing happened. there is not exception in CatLog or showing any error. i checked Manifest file and c_programs_start_51_100.xml file but i found nothing wrong still struggling find out the problem. The function Onclick() doesn't executed at single when i check in CatLog. please help me resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class C_Programs_Start_51_100 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView textViewC51;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.c_programs_start_51_100);

    textViewC51 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView51);
    textViewC51.setOnClickListener(this);       
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Log.d("press", "second" + view.getId());

    switch(view.getId()) {

    Log.d("press", "first");

    case R.id.textView51:

        Log.d("press", "first");

        Intent intent51 = new Intent(C_Programs_Start_51_100.this, C_Programs_P51.class);
        startActivity(intent51);

        Log.d("press", "second");

        break;



    }

}
```

}

// Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".First" >

     <ScrollView 
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/table_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/table_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/table_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/table_vertical_margin"
        >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" > 



        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/table_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/table_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/table_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/table_vertical_margin"

            >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView51"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="@string/txtPn51" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewC51"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:text="@string/txtC51" />
        </TableRow>


    </LinearLayout>
  </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The code should work properly. There is something wrong with xml, for instance some of ui elements overlap your `TextView`

Comment: post xml this code looks fine

Comment: Just try removing the **LinearLayout** in between the **TableRow** element.And make a test and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two textViews one with

`id = textView51`

`id = textViewC51`

in your onCreate you are trying to find the first textview and pass it to another

```
textViewC51 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView51);
```

Try to change the previous line with:

```
    textViewC51 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewC51);
```

and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to implement something when the user clicks the textview.If this is the case you can just use a spinner, Where you can implement the said functionality without much complexity

Answer (score -2):

you implemented the View.OnClickListener and I'm assuming that you also include in the xml the android:onclick attribute in your xml file?..

Comment: You don't need to because you call setOnClickListener.

Comment: Hey user3438885.Just talk if you know about the Android basics.If else just post comments.Not answers like this.